# Restore tfs collection from mdf/ldf

Tags: tfs

My server running TFS express crashed. I managed to mount the disk and extract mdf/ldf file for my TFS collection. Here is what I did next:

1. Built a new machine (with the same name/IP address) and installed SQL Express/TFS server express.
2. From SQL Server Management Studio, attached the mdf/ldf files. I can now see TFS_MyCollection as a new database.
3. From TFS Administrative console, clicked on "Attach Collection."

However, the new database is not being listed.

I went through a bunch of links on the Internet. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d949edf3-1795-448a-a1cc-39555ce87b50/tfs-2010-installation-error had a similar situation. Based on the suggestion, I had attached the database. I also looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869(VS.80).aspx. However, this one talks about using backup/restore, which is not my case.

I must be missing some configuration step. Please advice. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You cant just attach a collection that was never detached.

You need to unconfigure your TFS instance (tfconfig.exe setup /uninstall:all) and then restore all of the databases.

You will need to restore each collection and the configuration DB. They are currently a set. Once you have all of the databses attached/restored you need to run the setup and "configure application tier only".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx

You need to follow the documentation for moving hardware. Make sure that you follow each step.

Note: You should take backups!

Comment: Thank for your help. I had already looked at those steps. However, it didn't really work, most likely because of some mistake I am making. In any case, I am marking the answer as useful.